# Heroku console undefined method delete and or destroy

Tags: ruby-on-rails, heroku

Hi I'm trying to delete users by their ip addresses.

I'm using this one in first line.

```
dummy = User.find(:all, :conditions => {:current_sign_in_ip => '180.194.29.229'})
```

I've tried

```
dummy.delete

dummy.delete.all

dummy.destroy

dummy.destroy.all
```

But seems like not working.

Comment: Did you try `dummy.delete_all` ?

Comment: Yes. Still got error with NoMethodError: undefined method `delete_all'

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This:

```
dummy = User.delete_all( ["current_sign_in_ip = ?", '180.194.29.229'] )
```